# Limit TD text length

Tags: css, backgrid

I've a grid generated by backgrid.

And I want to limit text length, each td must be on one line.

width property on td has no effect.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: You can use `white-space:nowrap` and `overflow-x:hidden` for the `td`, that should hide extra characters and it won't break into a new line. Edit : Didn't see an answer has already been given.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on how you define 'limit', you can simply prevent wrapping, and control overflow:

```
td{
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

This will keep contents to one line, with an ellipsis being appended to the end if textual content exceeds the allowed width of the `td`

Answer (score 1):

you need to put 'td' tag's text in 'p' tag and give td tag a class like `<td class="content_td"><p>Your text</p></td>`
then you can write in CSS like

```
.content_td p {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```